# How can I search for a 1-d array in a 2-d array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a 2-d array in JavaScript.

```
var arr = [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f'], ['g', 'h'], ['i', 'k']];
```

I want to search for the 1-d array `['a', 'b']` or the 1-d array `['b', 'a']` in arr. What will be the most efficient method? 
Will using any other data structure make it more efficient. I methods for adding, traversing arr and searching for 1-d arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to define what it means for two arrays to be "equal". Because `somearray == otherarray` is only true if the two variables refer to the exact same instance of an Array object
(ie. `a = [1,2]; b = [1,2]; c = a;` allows `a == c` but `a != b`)

This is best done in a function. For instance, `areArraysEqual(a,b)`. In your case, this function will need to return `true` if the arrays contain the same elements, but not necessarily in the same order. Personally, I would suggest a `.sort()` on each array, then compare the elements one by one - after sorting, `a[0]` should equal `b[0]`, `a[1]` equals `b[1]`, and so on.

Now that you have your array comparison function, it's a simple matter of iterating through your big array, and for each one check if it is equal to your individual array. If it is, return the position you are at and stop.

Now go write some code, and come back with a specific problem if you have any :p

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand, but you can grab the first "element" with shift(), then you can manipulate it further.

```
var arr = [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f'], ['g', 'h'], ['i', 'k']].shift();
arr; // arr is now ['a', 'b']

for(var i=0; i<arr.length;i++){
  if(arr[i] == "b"){
     //matched 'b'
  }
}
```

From there you can search within it with a for loop. I hope I understood you correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm agree with @Niet the Dark Absol
And I think not bad idea before comparing the elements one by one to compare length, and sort array only with the same lenght like array that you are finding it's mor efficient than sorting all 1-d arrays.

```
function find(arr1d, arr2d) {
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr2d.length; ++i){
        if (arr2d[i].length == arr1d.length){
            var equal = true;
            for (var j = 0; j < arr1d.length; ++j){
                if (arr2d[i].indexOf(arr1d[j]) == -1){
                   equal = false;
                   break;
                }
            }
            if (equal)
                result.append(arr2d[i]);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

This solution no so efficient like with sorting, but if you will sort and you don't want to change you 2-d array you should copy data, it's very consuming, in this case my solution I think more efficient than with sorting.

Comment: Should be a comment on my answer :p

Comment: Isn't it more efficient to create a hash in this instance, rather than nested looping?

Comment: I'm not sure, but creating hashes consumes more memory and it takes time for creating it.